# Is assignment to nothing a sign of bad programming?

Tags: python, assignment-operator

I wrote a program that works perfectly, except I get feedback that says "you assigned the expression to nothing". Here is the code:

```
l = input('Please insert the numbers: ')

numbers = [int(i) for i in l.split(',')]

lower_limit = int(input('Please insert the lower limit: '))
upper_limit = int(input('Please insert the uppper limit: '))

boolean_list = []

for i in numbers:
       boolean_list.append(True) if (i >= lower_limit and i <= upper_limit ) else  
       boolean_list.append(False)    

print(boolean_list)
```

I can first initialize `boolean_list` and then assign logical values to it, but I believe it would be much slower than my first approach (given above). I'm completely new to programming so it isn't clear to me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There is more wrong here than assigning to nothing. You certainly shouldn't use an inline if like that.

Comment: can you please indent the code correctly?

Comment: @DanielRoseman could you please explain more ?

Comment: The auto-generated feedback is certainly wrong. But why use that conditional expression in the first place?

Comment: And `i >= lower_limit and i <= upper_limit` produces a `True` or `False` result already, so why not just append *that* rather than use such a huge expression? `boolean_list.append(i >= lower_limit and i <= upper_limit)` would suffice. Then replace the `for` loop with `append` calls with a list comprehension: `boolean_list = [i >= lower_limit and i <= upper_limit for i in numbers]`.

Comment: Oh, and you can use a chained comparison: `boolean_list = [lower_limit <= i <= upper_limit for i in numbers].`

Comment: You could also chain the conditionals: `boolean_list = [lower_limit <= i <= upper_limit for i in numbers]`

Comment: "works perfectly"? I beg to disagree, this code is  syntactically incorrect and does not work at all. At least In Python 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: @Błotosmętek the only syntactic error is that `boolean_list.append(False)` is on its own line without line continuation. I assume this is something OP did in attempt to format the code better, and isn't reflective of his actual code. Accounting for this makes the code run and perform as expected.

Comment: Questions like these may better fit on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Better fit on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option to avoid this problem is to get rid off your for loop, by using a list comprehension :

```
boolean_list = [i >= lower_limit and i <= upper_limit  for i in numbers]
```

This will use [list comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) that are a much more efficient way to build iterators.

Comment: also this is much more readable and... pythonic ;)

Comment: It's not using a generator, it's a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).